# Performance improvement of SQL Server table with millions of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server which has millions of records.

I was trying to do a select by passing id in the where condition, like this:

```
select id,processid value 
from table1 
where processid= 5
```

It's returning around 1 million records and took around 25 minutes to execute.

There is one index on the table. Do I need to create a separate non clustered index?

please see my table script

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Schema1].[Table1](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProcessId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [Amount2] [decimal](21, 6) NULL,
    [Amount1] [decimal](21, 6) NULL,
        [Amount3] [decimal](21, 6) NULL,
            [Amount4] [decimal](21, 6) NULL,
    [CreatedById] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedById] [int] NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Schema1_Table1] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Table1_INDEX_FG]
) ON [Allocation_DATA_FG]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Schema1].[Table1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CHK_Table1ComputeNode] CHECK  ((([ProcessId]%(3)+(1))=(2)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [Schema1].[Table1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CHK_Table1ComputeNode]
GO
```

I have to do performance improvement in a stored procedure which do have lots of joins with table. But this selection itself taking too much time.

Please give suggestions to improve the performance

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We can't just blindly make performance suggestions. You need to share the ddl for the table including existing indexes.

Comment: Why is the primary key index set to **non-clustered**? That's not the default - and typically isn't a good idea - unless you have very specific reasons for doing this - but these aren't obvious from the little information you've provided ....

Comment: Considering that you state `where id = 5` returns *"around 1 million records"*, then there's no way you can set `id` to be your `PRIMARY KEY`; a Primary Key needs to be unique.

Comment: You shouldn't create index if you are using only the primary key. For your procedure, you need to analysis the column frequently browsed, try to create some index and find the best for your procedure. Use the query plan to check the best index.

Comment: What is your table structure?  Is the ID an int?  If the datatypes are different it is doing implicit conversions and that takes time as well.

Comment: i edited my post and added the table design here. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Making your ID field the PRIMARY KEY (CLUSTERED index) will improve performance greatly. And a NONCLUSTERED index on processid will probably improve it more. Your nonclustered, primary key is the problem as @marc_s pointed out. There are implications to all of this, so definitely do this in a test environment before production.

Comment: So, *if* `id` is indeed your Primary Key, how does your query with the clause `WHERE id = 5` return 1 millions rows? Either that isn't your full query, or it's not your PK. Seems we're missing most of the pie here.

Comment: @Larnu Note that the field changed after the update... it's clearer now. `Id` is the (currently nonclustered) primary key but OP is querying by `processid`.

Comment: Thanks @JacobH I'd missed that.

Comment: thank you all for the suggestion. i contacted our dba team and they are telling id is not using anywhere so they changed it into nonclustered index. what they are suggesting is to add a clustered index to processid field will improve performance. what you guys think?

Comment: Well it's obviously being used as the unique, primary key on this table. Why would they change it to nonclustered? Just to slow down your queries? Or does this table have an absurd number of inserts or something? The logic makes no sense in this context.

Comment: thank you i changed processid to nonclustered and primary field to clustered. still its taking too much time. i do have 75 million records on this table. and my query is returning 70 millions records. any suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Optimal variant:

1. Since id is ever increasing identity field, change the primary key from non-clustered to clustered. Also this will prevent fragmentation.
2. Add non-clustered index on processid. It will be covered for your query. Which will make it ideal in terms of select performance

---

Less optimal:

In case if the primary key cannot be adjusted:

```
CREATE INDEX ProcessID on table1(ProcessID) INCLUDE (id)
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, if you just need to extract list of IDs for certain ProcessId and you do not want to create clustered index by ID you can create clustered index on "processid" column. If you do not want to create clustered index at all, create index by ProcessId with included ID:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_Table1 ON [Table1](processid) INCLUDE ([Id])
```

At second, your query can't return millions of records, because accordingly to CHECK CONSTRAINT [CHK_Table1ComputeNode] processid can only have values: 1,4,7,...